# Understand if Apache Telnet Client is connected and running

Tags: java, client, telnet

I have a Java Telnet Client implemented using org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient and I don't understand when the connection is up and running.
This is the connection part:

```
    static org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient tc = new org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient();

    TerminalTypeOptionHandler ttopt = new TerminalTypeOptionHandler("VT100", true, true, true, true); //VT52
    EchoOptionHandler echoopt = new EchoOptionHandler(true, false, true, false);
    SuppressGAOptionHandler gaopt = new SuppressGAOptionHandler(true, true, true, true);

    try
    {
        SecurityTelnetClient.tc.addOptionHandler(ttopt);
        SecurityTelnetClient.tc.addOptionHandler(echoopt);
        SecurityTelnetClient.tc.addOptionHandler(gaopt);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Error registering option handlers: " , e);
    }

    tc.connect("IP", "PORT");
```

This function return the connection state:

```
    public boolean isConnected(){
         return this.tc.isConnected();
    }
```

but even if this function returns true, in reality there are't more data sent to the channel from the Telnet Server. How can I understand that the connection is blocked?

Thanks

Comment: Generally the server is waiting for you to send it something. If you don't send anything you wil be blocked in the read method.

Comment: in my case, i dont send anything to the server, i wait for data from the server. And the connection maybe open all day long. I think that I can restart the connection every X minuts

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: When the app starts there aren't problems but after the night every morning I have to restart the telnet client connection, because doesn't work (don't receive nothing from the server) even if the isConnected() function return "True". So the question is why the function return true but the connection does't works fine?